# Que significa esta seccion de Eliminar Nodo de Lista en C

Tags: c, lista

Debajo esta el codigo completo para Eliminar el ultimo Nodo de una Lista simple enlazada y si funciona bien
La funcion es void deleteLastNode();

Pero Exactamente que significa esta parte?. Me parece que sobra
Porque cuando termine el bucle while tenemos al nodo toDelete en el ultimo lugar y a secondLastNode como penúltimo

```
if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
```

LA FUNCION deleteLastNode() ES ESTA

```
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
        }

        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}
```

PERO YO CREO QUE ESTO ES SUFICIENTE:

```
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }





            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;


        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}
```

EL codigo completo es este:
y la funcion es void deleteLastNode();

```
/**
 * C program to delete last node of Singly Linked List
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Structure of a node */
struct node {
    int data;          // Data
    struct node *next; // Address 
}*head;

void createList(int n);
void deleteLastNode();
void displayList();


int main()
{
    int n, choice;

    /*
     * Create a singly linked list of n nodes
     */
    printf("Enter the total number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    createList(n);

    printf("\nData in the list \n");
    displayList();

    printf("\nPress 1 to delete last node: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    /* Delete last node from list */
    if(choice == 1)
        deleteLastNode();

    printf("\nData in the list \n");
    displayList();

    return 0;
}


/*
 * Create a list of n nodes
 */
void createList(int n)
{
    struct node *newNode, *temp;
    int data, i;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    /*
     * If unable to allocate memory for head node
     */
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * Input data of node from the user
         */
        printf("Enter the data of node 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);

        head->data = data; // Link the data field with data
        head->next = NULL; // Link the address field to NULL

        temp = head;

        /*
         * Create n nodes and adds to linked list
         */
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

            /* If memory is not allocated for newNode */
            if(newNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter the data of node %d: ", i);
                scanf("%d", &data);

                newNode->data = data; // Link the data field of newNode with data
                newNode->next = NULL; // Link the address field of newNode with NULL

                temp->next = newNode; // Link previous node i.e. temp to the newNode
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

        printf("SINGLY LINKED LIST CREATED SUCCESSFULLY\n");
    }
}


/*
 * Delete last node of the linked list
 */
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
        }

        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}


/*
 * Display entire list
 */
void displayList()
{
    struct node *temp;

    /*
     * If the list is empty i.e. head = NULL
     */
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Data = %d\n", temp->data); // Print the data of current node
            temp = temp->next;                // Move to next node
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola. Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Estoy bastante seguro de que puedes proporcionar un comportamiento equivalente **en bastantes menos líneas**. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin comprendí ,

```
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)   //Si se cumple la LISTA ESTA VACIA
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }

    else      //SINO LA LISTA NO ESTA VACIA
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        //COMIENZA EL BARRIDO DE NODOS DE CABEZA HASTA EL FINAL
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }
       //TERMINADO EL BUCLE SE HA OBTENIDO QUE *toDelete apunta al Ultimo
      //Nodo y secondLastNode al Penultimo NODO y apunta al Ultimo

      //Pero ese BUCLE WHILE NO AVANZARA  NADA, SI LA LISTA Tiene UN SOLO 
    //NODO
      //Y SI no aplica entonces aun toDelete==head  y como hay un solo 
      //Nodo entonces, mando a cabeza=NULL que es lo mismo que aux=NULL
     //DE ESA MAnera elimino el Unico NODO  que habia

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }

        else   //si toDelete no es igual a headm entonces seguimos 
               //con el resultado del while
        {
          //tenemos a *anterior  y *aux, 
          //mando a anterior->siguiente=NULL (para que sea el ultimo)
          //libero a aux con free(aux) y lo desaparezco

            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
        }

        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
```

Bueno eso es lo que entendi , gracias por su paciencia